Visuallizing complex vectors?
I'm learning Linear algebra course, and i was stumbled with an expamle that showing how the complex vectors are perpendicular when the dot product equals to zero.
The question was to find the dot product to the following two vectors $\vec{u}$ = (1 , i), $\vec{v}$ = (i , 1), and using the following relation of the inner product of complex vectors $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \sum u_{i}^\star v_{i}$, the answer is that the two previous vecotrs are perpendicullar by the value of the inner product is zero. My question is when im visualizing these vectors in a complex plane i can not see any orthogonality between these vectors instead they are at the same point at the complex plane, how to visualize the orthogonality between these vectors then ?!

u and v are the same vector right?

They are the same, but it seems they are not, because using the norm definition the norm of the same vector should not equals to zero.

Ah sorry now that you edited the question they are different

The confusion is coming from the fact that these vectors do not belong to the complex plane, aka $\mathbb C$, but rather in $\mathbb C^2$, which is not the complex plane. Note that if $v\in \mathbb C$, then $v=(x,y)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb R$. What you have is two vectors whose coordinates are each complex, that is, each component comes from $\mathbb C$.
In $\mathbb C^2$, $(1,i)$ and $(i,1)$ indeed are orthogonal, so it checks out. Here's another way you can see it. Write $1$ as $(1,0)$ and $i$ as $(0,1)$ (as you would do if they were on the plane) and then forget the bracketing. You can see these vectors are orthogonal in $\mathbb R^4$. This can be formalised, but I will leave you to it.

Thanks for your simple answer,  i found my mistake. Thanks

Visualizing that these vectors are orthogonal is quite hard because there you would have to visualize them in a 4-dimensional space.

@quarague Yes :D it's hard to see, but not hard to see. Formally, note that the first vector lies in a plane (say $XW$) that is orthogonal to the plane the second vector is in ($YZ$) [One can start visualizing in $\mathbb R^3$ using the $XYZ$ basis by dropping the last coordinate, and then noting that adding the last coordinate only moves the first vector in an orthogonal plane, which is hard to visualize, but not hard to see :p].


using the following relation of the inner product of complex vectors $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \sum u_{i}^\star v_{i}$

That relation is not some derivable identity, but is simply a definition of the notation on the left side as meaning the formula right side.

when im visualizing these vectors in a complex plane i can not see any orthogonality between these vectors instead they are at the same point at the complex plane

Here $\vec{u} = (1 , i)$ and $\vec{v} = (i , 1)$. Why do you call these "at the same point"?  They are both in $\mathbf C^2$, which you can not visualize, and they are most definitely not the same since their first coordinates are not equal and their second coordinates also are not equal.
There is no visualization once mathematical concepts get into a high enough dimension. Instead we may gain intuition by (i) thinking about lower-dimensional cases or (ii) by turning complex numbers into real numbers, but this can be very misleading sometimes, e.g., solutions to the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in $\mathbf R^2$ form a bounded region but solutions to $z^2 + w^2 = 1$ in $\mathbf C^2$ form an unbounded region since you can let $z$ be any complex number you want and then solve for $w$ since all complex numbers (unlike real numbers) have a square root.  At the same time, solutions to $z\overline{z} + w\overline{w}  = 1$ in $\mathbf C^2$ form a bounded region since the equation is the same as $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$, so $z$ and $w$ satisfying that equation are both bounded.
We refer to $\mathbf C = \mathbf R^2$ as a plane, but that descriptive label really is geometrically accurate only when dealing with real coordinates. When our scalars are complex numbers, $\mathbf C$ is more accurately the "complex line" but you won't hear it called that. Instead, for historical reasons it is still called the complex plane despite not being $2$-dimensional as a complex vector space, and you won't hear $\mathbf C^2$ called the "complex plane" despite being $2$-dimensional as a complex vector space.
Ultimately, as Hironaka once said, when we have no way to rely on direct  geometric visualization in high dimensions, we need to rely on algebra, as it works in the same way in any number of dimensions.  Thus gain intuition about inner products in $\mathbf R^n$ by seeing how it works when $n = 2$ or $3$, appreciate that the algebraic rules about inner products continue to hold in $\mathbf R^n$ for all $n$, and in the setting of $\mathbf C^n$ with the alternate inner product that involves complex conjugation on the coordinates of one vector check that the useful algebraic rules for the inner product on $\mathbf R^n$ continue to hold for the inner product on $\mathbf C^n$. There is no faithful way to directly "see" perpendicularity in $\mathbf C^2$ any more than there is to see it in $\mathbf R^5$.
To visualize perpendicular vectors in $\mathbf C^2$, just draw perpendicular vectors in $\mathbf R^2$ and pretend it is $\mathbf C^2$. There is no better way. In complex geometry, people "draw" a complex curve like $z = w^2$ by drawing the real curve $y = x^2$ and acknowledging that not every aspect of the complex setting is going to be captured by looking at the real setting.
Brad Osgood discusses how to think about orthogonality in the complex setting in his lectures on Fourier analysis. See Lecture 4 here. During 23:45 to 25:21 he emphasizes that we reason by analogy, and that any expectation you should be able to directly see orthogonal complex vectors, or in his case complex functions with inner product $\int_0^1 f(t)\overline{g(t)}\,dt$, is absurd ("Don't beat yourself up trying to do that"). The fact that the formula $\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi t)\cos(2\pi t)\,dt = 0$ lets us regard $\sin(2\pi t)$ and $\cos(2\pi t)$ as "orthogonal functions" even though their usual graphs in absolutely no way look orthogonal shows even in the case of real functions with an inner product we can't expect to visualize orthogonality in a direct way but we can still make use of the purely algebraic consequences of vanishing inner products by using a geometric language to describe things we may do with them (orthogonal, orthonormal, projection, etc).

Thanks for all of the details, i learned a lot now thanks.

I object to the complex line comment, the reason the terminology isn’t popular is simply because a “complex line” doesn’t have an ordering, and so doesn’t behave like a line in any sensible geometric sense (ie topologically, it’s still a plane)

@AwkwardWhale geometric terminology is widely used when doing linear algebra or algebraic geometry over general fields $K$, even $K$ that do not have an ordering, e.g., the set of all solutions $(x,y)$ in $K^2$ to $ax + by = c$ where $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$ is called a line through the origin whether or not $K$ is ordered. And we use geometric terms with metric spaces, such as balls and discs, even when the balls and discs in some metric spaces don't resemble actual balls or discs in Euclidean space.

Note that the definition of the inner product on a complex vector space has not be chosen completely arbitrarily, and many of the properties of $\mathbb C^2$ as a 2-dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space coincide with its properties as a 4-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space. Also, some mathematical concepts are "hard to visualise in high dimension" but can be visualised by looking at a projection on an easier-to-visualise lower-dimensional space (and making sure that you only authorise yourself conclusions where a property of the projection implies a property of the original object)

You've got good answers noting that your two vectors are elements of the complex Cartesian plane $\mathbf{C}^{2}$, which as a real vector space is four-dimensional.
To complement with a picture and a geometric perspective:

The following unit vectors are mutually-orthogonal:
\begin{align*}
  e_{1} &:= (1, 0), & e_{2} &:= (0, i); \\
  e_{3} &:= (0, 1), & e_{4} &:= (i, 0).
\end{align*}
Consequently, every vector in the real plane spanned by $\{e_{1}, e_{2}\}$ (including the unit vectors represented by the thicker blue circle) is orthogonal to every vector in the real plane spanned by $\{e_{3}, e_{4}\}$ (the thinner circle). Particularly, these two planes intersect in one point, the origin.
The vector $(1, i) = e_{1} + e_{2}$ lies in the first plane; the vector $(i, 1) = e_{3} + e_{4}$ lies in the second.



Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Very nice question.
Let's think through this:
Suppose we have complex number $z \in \mathbb{C}$. We know that if we represent $z$ in its algebraic form using real numbers, we have $z = x + iy$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Geometrically, we represent the number $z$ by the ordered pair $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. This means that we need two scalars, $x$ and $y$ to represent a complex number z on the plane.
Now, if we try to think of a number $(z,w)$ on the plane $\mathbb{C}^2$, then it means that we have to represent the two entries $z, w$ this time as two complex numbers, that is, we need scalars $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z = a + ib$ and $w = c + id$. Therefore the number $(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2$(in your example represented by the number $(i,1)$ and $(i,1)$ ) have their algebraic representations as $(a + ib, c + id)$.
In the context of linear algebra, we say that the $\mathbb{C}^2$ $\textit{vector space over}$ $\mathbb{R}$ has dimension 4, represented by $dim_{\mathbb{R}}\, \mathbb{C}^2 = 4$.  So your question can be interpreted in the sense that, if we want to visualize this operations usian the plane vectors from your example, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, we would need something like two cartesian planes, where each one of them is orthogonal to each other, in a 4-dimensional space.

Thanks for your simple clarification, now i can see it clearly, thanks.
